# How to read my messages from Inbox or sent items from a specific email address and within a particular interval?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

i am working in graph explorer API to read the email of my account. the idea is to pass an email address and a date interval to Graph API and it should return me the same Messages Associated with this email.it could be from sent item and inbox **can be both**.
 i am useing below api:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$Search="Aj****@t**maxa****icas.com
and Sent >= 2018-05-09"
```

but this is giving  Messages from my inbox not from sent Email.Can any 1 help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages$search="Received>=2018-05-16T11:55:01 AND Participants:A***@tr*****c**as.com"&$top=10
```

This works fine for me.

**you can pass the yyyy-mm-dd format also in the Revived date.**

Answer (score 7):

The `/me/messages` endpoint works against the mailbox but there are exceptions. Certain mail folders are specifically excluded: Outbox, Send Items, Junk, Deleted Items. In general, folders that contain outgoing or otherwise ignored mail (i.e. junk, trash) require special handling.

In order to work against a specific folder, you need to specify that folder in your URL path:

```
/me/mailFolders/{folder}/messages
```

The `{folder}` can be folder's `id` (obtained by listing the folders via [`/me/mailFolders`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_mailfolders)) or a "well-known folder name" that is [pre-defined by Exchange](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mailfolder) (`ArchiveRoot`, `ConversationHistory`, `DeletedItems`,  `Drafts`, `Inbox`, `JunkEmail`, `Outbox`, or **`SentItems`**).

So to obtain the messages in the Sent Items folder, you would call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages
```

Comment: @Mark Lafleur : Thanks for your reply but i am not sure in which folder the search email exists . don't we have any solution we can search on entire outlook not only in a specific folder?

Comment: Technically `/me/messages` will cover the entire mailbox. There are however some exceptions. I will update my answer.

Comment: $search="Received>=2018-05-16T11:55:01 AND Participants:A***@tr*****c**as.com"&$top=10         This work fine  for me.Thanks

Comment: Awesome work, I am looking for same solution but inbox. I want to get all the messages from inbox but issue is that it only show email but I want to have reply email as well of all emails. Thank you.